# Project does not start on Tomcat after converting to Idea Project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, resteasy

I have an exists eclipse maven project uses **JBoss resteasy** and **spring framework** (work fine).

Now, I want to convert is to **Intellij idea ultimate 15** maven project but it isn't working (built OK), I have a trouble to deploy it to tomcat 8 (server just deploy default manager and hang up).

I can not find any error log of a server for this trouble. I have searched in google but can not find anything about this trouble, please help me.

Comment: Without logs nobody could help you. I suppose it could be not a problem with converting but with code or configs itself. Try to find logs at ${catalina.base}/logs. If it works correctly with Eclipse?

Comment: There is no such thing as an eclipse maven or intellij maven project. There is only a maven project. It should work regardless of the IDE. If not you are doing things outside of maven which is something you shouldn't be doing anyway.